# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build

I keep running into this issue while trying to build the android project I'm working on in android studio. Can someone help me figure out what it means?

I'm using:

- macOs 11.3
- android studio 4.1.3

```html
> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /Users/fsara/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
    ...org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 18s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: Can you check the buildToolVersion in your build.gradle and make sure that you have that SDK installed. Go to preferences -> SDK Manager to check the SDK. Looks like the latest SDK license was not accepted, you might want to try this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you miss Android SDK.
For me,my compileSdkVersion is 29,but i donnot download 29 SDK.
i open File>Settings>Appearance&Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK,and download Android Q SDK,it works.